# Rails: what is wrong with this route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

For some strange reason cardsets_path('my') generates "/cardsets.my" instead of "/cardsets/my". Please explain why?

config/routes.rb:

```
match '/cardsets/:type', :to => 'cardsets#index', :requirements => { :type => /my|public/ }, :as => 'cardsets'

resources :users do
  resources :cardsets do
  end
end
```

rake routes:

```
cardsets /cardsets/:type(.:format) {:controller=>"cardsets", :action=>"index"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't it be

```
cardsets_path(:type => 'my')
```

However, type is a reserved word in rails.